# rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet).location not Swift?

Tags: swift2, range, nsrange

Been going bonkers with this one as all samples I find use the NSRange version but in Swift 2 this method returns a Range so no location to test.

I know that the result of a not found is {NotFound,0} but don't have a scooby doo how to test for it?

```
if (contact.facebook!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet.invertedSet).location != NSNotFound){...}
```

errors but I cant find out how to query Range

Comment: Add the exact error messages to your question.

Comment: furthermore, what are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: apologies, I have neglected to update this ticket!  I ended up scrapping the way I was doing things and so do not need this snippet any more.

Answer (score 9):

Cast it to a NSString

```
let objcString = string as NSString

let characterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet            

if objcString.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet).location != NSNotFound {
     return false
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 renames: objcString.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)